# Is a solenoid piston strong enough to lock a water tubling?

Tags: arduino-uno

My question is about hardware that i'll control with my arduino... Not Arduino itself (So I don't know if I'm in the right section ... :s)

My project is to create a cocktail machine at the cheapest price.

I was wondering if [this kind of solenoid piston](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11015) would be strong enough to seals a plastic pipe like [this one](https://www.gearbest.com/robot-vacuum/pp_47721.html) ?

My idea from now is to use only 1 water pump ([as this one](https://www.banggood.com/12V-Mini-DC-Brushless-Garden-Fountain-Pump-Hydrological-Cycle-Submersible-Water-Pump-p-1009353.html?rmmds=buy)) and connect all the pipes from the bottles with some Y and control which one is giving the liquid by controling pistons that are going to compress the tube.

I'm open to all advices you could give me and new ideas ... I saw that there's also [solenoid valves](https://www.banggood.com/12V-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-Magnetic-DC-NC-Water-Air-Inlet-Flow-Switch-12-p-1023361.html?rmmds=buy) ... But I only find it in 12V ... Does it exist in 5V ?

Comment: Unlikely at best. You should either use proper valves or consider a geared motor / servo (*not* a model one) to rotate a cam to compress the tube.

Comment: If you can't find what you want in 5V then you will need to control them with the correct voltage. It's not rocket surgery.

Comment: You'll crack the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The pump you are looking at is to powerful for you application: 350 liters/hour, or little less than 5 ltr/min. It will fill a 250 ml glass in about 3 seconds!

The solenoid cost you $5 a piece, but you still need a valve and a way to attach solenoid, valve and tubing.

Also, your idea means liquids will get mixed inside the tubes. And nobody wants a trace of whiskey in his Vodka Screwdriver.

You must visit [The Inebriator](https://www.theinebriator.com/), a cocktail mixing machine. His design have one tube for every bottle pouring liquid into the glass.

[image: Cocktail Mixing Machine]

As they note, they have in version 2.0

> Switching mixers from a pressurised system with valves to using pumps
>   – This slows the pouring, but vastly simplifies the machine as a
>   whole. We have a capacity for 16 pumps

They don't use valves, but pumps. I recomend a peristaltic pump ($7 on Aliexpress), like this:

[image: Peristaltic pump]

They don't touch the fluid, easy to mount, and are a very precise delivery mechanism, like in this video https://youtu.be/GdTUIwj5ros, showing an Arduino controlling a pump to 1ml precision:

[image: Arduino controlled pump]

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't touch the fluid" ? Fluid pass throught it no ? 
But is there some way to use only 1 pump ? (cause 1 pump cost almost 8~10$ ... And if I want 6 diffents bottles I'll need 6 pumps so ... )

Comment: @Seba99 [the soft pipe gets squeezed so a pocket of fluid moves along](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump) that way pump internals don't need to be touched by the pumped medium.

Comment: No ! There's no mix "inside" the tubes ! I just don't want to make a little train that moves the glass ... Imo it's just complicated for nothinhg ! I just want all my tube coming in the same place where the standing glass is ... And then just choose which tube to "activate" But seem's like complicated and I'm going for six ( for now the idea is 6 bottles) peristaltics pumps...

Comment: But there's is 3V / 6V and 12V pump ... Which one should I take ? Can I use the 6V one on the 5V output of arduino ?